# Why is the conditional rendering of this web component not working in Stencil?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, stenciljs

My original code was this:

`{this.checked && <ifx-icon icon="check-12"></ifx-icon>}`

and this works, but every time `checked` is `true`, there is this small movement when the `ifx-icon` appears. The whole element moves down and then up again. I tried so many things to make it stop, including making the parent `inline-flex`, using `vertical-align`, playing with the `line-height` etc. but nothing works! It keeps moving, and I don't know why.

For that reason, I have decided to make the icon name itself conditional, while the `ifx-icon` component always stays there. So, I tried this:

`{<ifx-icon icon={this.checked ? "check-12" : ""}></ifx-icon>}`

but now the icon is not rendered at all! Even when `checked` becomes `true`, the icon does not render. I get the error `icon not found` which is an error I've made for when the typed icon does not exist. So, this means the `check-12` icon name is not added properly, perhaps. I don't know.

So, then I tried to conditionally render two `ifx-icon`s, one empty and one with the icon name:

```
{this.checked 
  ? <ifx-icon icon="check-12"></ifx-icon>
  : <ifx-icon icon="asd"></ifx-icon>}
```

and once again it was not working! When `checked` is `true`, I get `icon not found`.
However, if instead of the empty icon, I render a plain text, i.e. this:

```
{this.checked 
  ? <ifx-icon icon="check-12"></ifx-icon>
  : 'asd'}
```

..now it works, but once again, there is this movement up and down that I don't want.

So, how do I get rid of that movement, and why is the conditional rendering not working in the other 2 cases?

For context, I have the following styling applied:

```
ifx-icon:empty { 
  display: none;
}
```

```css
:host { 
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.checkbox__container { 
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 8px;
    margin: 0;

    & .checkbox__wrapper { 
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: tokens.$color-bg-white;
        border: 1px solid #575352;
        border-radius: 1px;
        flex: none;
        order: 0;
        flex-grow: 0;

        & .icon__wrapper { 
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
        }

        &:hover { 
            background-color: #EEEDED;
            border: 1px solid #575352;
            border-radius: 1px;
            flex: none;
            order: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
        }

        &.disabled { 
            background-color: #BFBBBB;
            border-radius: 1px;
            flex: none;
            order: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
        }

        &.checked { 
            background-color: #0A8276;
            border-radius: 1px;
            flex: none;
            order: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
            color: tokens.$color-white;

                &:hover { 
                    background-color: #08665C;
                    border-radius: 1px;
                    flex: none;
                    order: 0;
                    flex-grow: 0;
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

My component looks like this:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="checkbox__container" onClick={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this)}>
        <div 
        class={`checkbox__wrapper ${this.checked ? 'checked' : ""} ${this.disabled ? 'disabled' : ""}`}>
          <div class="icon__wrapper">
          {<ifx-icon icon={this.checked ? "check-12" : ""}></ifx-icon>}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="label">
          <slot />
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figured out where did the movement come from. It was coming from the `vertical-align`, so I solved it by adding `vertical-align: top` to the `:host`;

```
:host { 
vertical-align: top;
}
```